# Googlesheet filter return all result if empty condition

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to return all result if the condition is empty, instead of #N/A, possible? Thank you

Sample sheet attached

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r8da7eOxEkx6JlAFQhU9zN055gGQfSyPAXVgpPEF2Ek

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSCPu.jpg)

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(A3:B9,if(I1="",B3:B9<>"",B3:B9=I1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that's genius, never thought of If formula can use like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
=ifna(filter(A3:B9,B3:B9=$F$1),{A3:B9})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using QUERY:

```
=QUERY(A3:B9,"where 0=0"&IF(I1="",," and B="&I1))
```

This is particularly useful if you have more than one condition.